# How do I find out what directory my console app is running in?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

How do I find out what directory my console app is running in with C#?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

To get the directory where the .exe file is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

To get the current directory:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: Thanks. Helps when the C# .exe is in one folder but is invoked from another folder (eg: when it's on the system PATH)

Comment: For .NET Core, it is `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`.

Answer (score 17):

Depending on the rights granted to your application, whether [shadow copying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx) is in effect or not and other invocation and deployment options, different methods may work or yield different results so you will have to choose your weapon wisely. Having said that,
all of the following will yield the same result for a fully-trusted console application that is executed locally at the machine where it resides:

```
Console.WriteLine( Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location );
Console.WriteLine( new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath );
Console.WriteLine( Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0] );
Console.WriteLine( Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName );
```

You will need to consult the documentation of the above members to see the exact permissions needed.

Answer (score 5):

Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

Answer (score 4):

In .NET, you can use `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get the directory from which the process was started.
`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will tell you the location of the currently executing assembly (that's only interesting if the currently executing assembly is loaded from somewhere different than the location of the assembly where the process started).

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your .Net core console application project name is DataPrep.

Get Project Base Directory:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

**Output:** ~DataPrep\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2

```
Get Project .csproj file directory:
string ProjectDirPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\..\..\"));
Console.WriteLine(ProjectDirPath);
```

**Output:** ~DataPrep\

Answer (score 1):

On windows (not sure about Unix etc.) it is the first argument in commandline.

In C/C++ firts item in argv*

WinAPI - GetModuleFileName(NULL, char*, MAX_PATH)

Comment: Yes, it's the same in .NET, too.  First arg is always the full path of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Application.StartUpPath;

Comment: care to link to some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppContext.BaseDirectory` for .net5.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use method [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-7.0):

```
string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Console.WriteLine("Working dir: " + currentDirectory);
```