# Best way to implement file access in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, file, coding-style

Scenario - I need to access an HTML template to generate a e-mail from my Business Logic Layer.  It is a class library contains a sub folder that contains the file.  When I tried the following code in a unit test:

```
string FilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\templates\MyFile.htm", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
string FilePath1 = string.Format(@"{0}\templates\MyFile.htm", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

It was using the C:\WINNT\system32\ or the ASP.NET Temporary Folder directory.

What is the best to access this file without having to use an app.config or web.config file?

[This is using a WCF Service]

Comment: [Related question (console app instead of class library)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97312/how-do-i-find-out-what-directory-my-console-app-is-running-in-with-c)

Comment: I ended up storing the file path in the web.config file.

Answer (score 6):

You're running this from an ASP.Net app right? Use `Server.MapPath()` instead.

Also take a look at `System.IO.Path.Combine()` for concatenating paths.

[Edit]
Since you can't use `System.Web`, try this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Or `GetEntryAssembly()`.

Comment: It is being used by a WCF Service.

Comment: Hmm, my WCF experience is very limited, do you have access to the Server property? There should be something similar regardless.

Comment: No, unless I add the System.Web namespace reference

Answer (score 1):

I belive you are looking for

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: This will only work with the System.Windows.Form namespace.  I am using a class library

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on my site! I haven't been working on just this for the last 2 years!!!

I added this inside my system.serviceModel block of the web.config. It seems to make all the paths relative to where your service is installed.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
```

better late than never?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath( "~/templates/myfile.htm" )
```

Comment: This is actually implemented in a class library file that is reference within the WCF Service.  I can not use any System.Web because it is not an ASP.NET application

Comment: Just because it's an ASP.NET application doesn't mean you can't use System.Web