# Command line current working directory in a console app

Tags: c#, windows, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what directory my console app is running in with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97312/how-do-i-find-out-what-directory-my-console-app-is-running-in-with-c)

How to get current working directory of a console that runs a program so I could resolve relative paths passed as program args?

Lets say I've put my program here: `c:\tools\program.exe`
But I'm invoking it from various places. Lets say I'm here: `C:\Users\Me\Documents\` and I run this command `program.exe --src=somefile.txt --dest=subdir\otherfile.txt`

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` and `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will return `c:\tools` but I would like to be able to resolve `somefile.txt` and `subdir\oterfile.txt` paths that are relative to `C:\Users\Me\Documents\`.

> ====== UPDATE ======
>
> Thank you for your help. It seems that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` works as expected. It turned out that in my case the problem was caused by Xenocode's Postbuild tool (now called Spoon Virtual Application Studio) that I occasionally use to "pack" all program's files (including dlls, config, etc.) into one executable. It's very handy, but in this case the "virtualization" feature messed up my program's `Environment` variables. I've managed to solve that issue.

Comment: This will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path.

Comment: well, if that files are past like a parameters, may be the easiets solution is just save the path past, or not ?

Comment: How are you calling the exe? Do you set the path environment variable?

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis - Yes, I've set the PATH variable so I won't have to type full program path every time.

Comment: Are you invoking it manually from the command prompt, or programmatically from a C# program?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Environment.CurrentDirectory gives you the Current Working Directory

Let me show a simple example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Startup: " + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"D:\temp";
        Console.WriteLine("After:" + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    }
}
```

Now I create two folders named `D:\temp` and `D:\temp2`
I put the executable in `D:\temp`
Open a command prompt and set the current working directory with `cd D:\temp2`
From that directory I run `..\temp\mytestapp.exe`

the output is

```
Startup: D:\temp2
After: D:\temp
```

As a curiosity:

this was the documentation for [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in Net 1.1

> Gets and sets the fully qualified path of the current directory; that
>   is, the directory from which this process starts.

and this is the documentation in NET 4.0

> Gets or sets the fully qualified path of the current working
>   directory.

Comment: I don't get it. With your example I get `Startup: D:\temp`. Note that I do not run the program by providing full path to the executable - I've set PATH variable to point to the directory where the executable sits.

Comment: Tested again, this time I have set the PATH variable to d:\temp and moved away the command prompt to another directory. Running from this other directory (without giving a partial path) it prints the name of this other directory and then changes to d:\temp.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right - see my edit for details.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Environment` and `Path` classes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx

```
var fqn = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "somefile.txt")
```

But to play with your documents you need:

```
var fqn = Path.Combine(
     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Person),
     "somefile.txt");
```

`fqn' is TLA for fully qualified name

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns the path where the executable is located, in my case `c:\tools\`. "My documents" was just an example - I can't hardcode that.

Comment: I don't think so, Environment.CurrentDirectory gives the Current working Directory

Comment: @Steve - I've tested that. In my case `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns `c:\tools`. That's where the executable is located. But I don't care about that path. I want to know the command line current directory - the directory where user was when he/she run the program.

Comment: OP has two questions posed as one!  First how to get a file in 'current directory'.  Secondly how to get a file in the `My Documents` folder.

Comment: @RichardSchneider - `My Documents` is just an example. This can be any directory.

Comment: `CurrentDirectory` is always where the user was when the program was invoked.  It is NOT the same as ystem.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, unless some other got in your way!