# Console App Get Full Path for Filename in Args

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

So, I have a simple console app which takes one parameter: filename.

Now, when I run it like this:

```
program.exe "C:\Temp\list.json"
```

It works since I have passed a full file path.

What I want to achieve is next:
I want to CD into C:\Temp and from there I want to call a file like:

```
"C:\Program Files\WS\program.exe" list.json
```

Basically, I want to pass in only the file name and from that construct the full file path.

How is this achievable?

I tried finding out if I can get the current directory from Terminal where I am, in my case, it would be C:Temp, but I did not find any answers for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that.

When you execute the below commands:

```
CD c:\TEMP
"C:\Program Files\WS\program.exe" list.json
```

The current directory for your program.exe would be C:\TEMP.

You can construct full path using below c# code.

```
//// assuming fileName contains the input file name
var fullPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
```

Hope this works.

Reference: [Stackoverflow Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587140/command-line-current-working-directory-in-a-console-app)